# "Services marketing" vs "marketing services"

Tags: word-choice, construction

I surfed the internet and found both terms, but I couldn’t figure out which one is more suitable in the following context:

Consider that company A persuades company C to buy some product from company B.
Now, company A would invoice company B for its services.

How should it be written on the invoice: **services marketing** or **marketing services**?

I guess *"marketing services"*, but I’m not hundred-percent sure, and wonder whether both terms can be used in this context.

Comment: Company A shall charge Company B for its *marketing service.* Ask yourself, which service did company A provide? *marketing service.* :)

Comment: I guess so, but can't go both?

Comment: These phrases have a modifier-head structure.  Marketing services are services, services marketing is marketing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Services marketing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Services_marketing) is defined by wikipedia as *"a sub field of marketing which covers the marketing of both goods and services"*.

**Marketing services**, as snailplane succinctly explains in the comments, are services. In this context, a **service** is *"the application of specialized competences (knowledge and skills) through deeds, processes, and performances"*.

In economics, a [**good**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_%28economics%29) is classified as **goods**, when they are tangible, otherwise they are **services**.

---

Thus, in the context you describe:

- **marketing services** is appropriate because company A has promoted company B's product and company B gets invoiced for it.
- **services marketing** would also be appropriate because, per wikipedia's definition, *"services marketing"* includes the marketing of both, goods and services.

Comment: So was my understanding too, but like I said wasn’t hundred-percent sure. +1 for you confirmed it. Your links were my searches too.

Answer (score 0):

Services marketing, would be providing marketing for specific services.

Marketing services would be describing the actual function that the marketing company is providing.

Answer (score 0):

Out of Services marketing vs. marketing services, I'd go for *marketing service.*

Consider Companies' names: A = Admire Marketing, B = Bristol and C = Core

That's because the Admire provided its services to *market* Bristol's product that Core goes for. So, it'll be the invoice of Admire's **marketing service.** Ask yourself, *which service did Admire provide? The marketing service.*

Answer ends here.

---

As you asked in comment - *can't I go with both.* You cannot. Because there, Admire did (Bristol's) *Product's Marketing* and not *Service Marketing.* You said - *company A persuades company C to buy some **product** from company B.*

Now what if *Company A persuades company C to go for some **service** from company B*.

Then Admire shall send invoice of Bristol's ***services' marketing*** (note that apostrophe). However, **I won't recommend this.**

Admire's **Marketing Service** is clear.